# Увеличивается количество используемой памяти в Entity Manager (Symfony + Doctrine)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Всем доброго времени суток!

В своем проекте использую Symfony 3 и Doctrine. Стоит задача обработать большой объем данных и для каждого элемента этого объема обновить информацию в базе. 
Соответственно, есть цикл foreach такого вида:

```
foreach ($array as $item)
{
    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Model')->find($id);
    $entity->setParameter($value);
    $entity->flush();
}
```

Дело в том, что после каждой итерации цикла количество используемой памяти растет и если количество элементов в обрабатываемом массиве около десятков тысяч, использование памяти повышается даже до гигабайта.

Читал, в том числе на англоязычном StackOverflow, про использование конструкций

- $em->clear();
- $this->em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
- gc_collect_cycles();

Но ничего из этого не помогает и память с каждой итерацией все так же увеличивается. Надеюсь на вашу помощь и заранее благодарю!

Comment: Стоит посмотреть, что именно течет, вот список тулз: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23779807/2908793

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может зависить от многих факторов, не только от Доктрины (например, от версии *PHP*). Также не совсем понятно, зачем вы делаете `flush()` внутри цикла `foreach` (т.е., исходя из содержания вопроса ~10 000 раз). `flush()` дергает метод `UnitOfWork::commit()`, который внутри себя много чего интересного делает, и некоторые из этих операций, например: перебор и сохранения снэпшотов, при определенных обстоятельствах (как упоминалось выше, вплоть до версии языка), потенциально могут быть источниками утечек памяти. Сам по себе паттерн *UnitOfWork* и его конкретная реализация в *Doctrine* предпологают (в большинстве случаев) не сохранение каждой сущностей по отдельности, а одноразовый вызов `EntityManager::flush()` в конце транзакции.

Вот хорошая статья: http://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/08/07/doctrine2-batch-processing.html, которая описывает как раз Ваш кейс: обработку больших объемов данных с помощью *Doctrine*. Подраздел **Mass object processing** - полностью Ваш.

Плюс не могу не заметить, что если функционал не сильно отличается от приведенного в примере (проапдейтить пару полей в большем к-ве строк), то это типичный пример, когда всяко лучше просто использовать прямой запрос к базе безо всяких *ORM* (понимаю, что на проекте могут быть ограничения, которые не зависят от Вас, и которые не позволяют прибегнуть к "сырому запросу"), либо, если *ORM*, то хотя бы через какой-то *query builder* сделать запрос. *Если* требуется плюс-минус такой же функционал, то нет никаких объективных причин создавать 10 000 объектов и бегать по ним в цикле.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ! Честно сказать, не знал про нюанс относительно flush(). А вот на статью натыкался при поиске, но читал, по-видимому, невнимательно.